# In opensearch while I use point in time pagination method, I was unable to get more than 10000 hits why?

Tags: opensearch, point-in-time, opensearch-security-plugin

I use 2.6 version with "point_in_time_full_access" have allowed actions as "manage_point_in_time". I was able to create PIT but while search I was unable to give size more than 10000.

I was expecting to get hits more than 10K